# Looking for a short story no later than 1980's about a boy who finds the tomb of a feline space warrior on earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the story the boy finds the entrance to a tomb in a hill, where he finds the weapons of a dead feline warrior.  Putting on the helmet enhances his senses.  At the end of the story he is medically examined by a computer and restored to perfect health, before the tomb is removed from earth to prevent it being found again.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a short story, but this bears a remarkable resemblance to Robert Westall's young adult novel ["Urn Burial"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_Burial_%28novel%29). The boy, the tomb, the feline warrior, and the medical examination are all definitely present in this book.

You can find a more in-depth exploration of the book's plot and themes [here](http://onlinebooksummary.blogspot.com/2010/11/urn-burial.html).